# Unable to download files or save cookies using internet explorer

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I am experiencing technical difficulties with Internet explorer 11.

Since I have upgraded my PC to 64 bit windows 7 I am now unable to download any files from any website. The browser will not save any cookies either so I cannot stay logged into any websites.

*I am also unable to view images on any emails via outlook 2010*

Chrome works fine.

I have attempted the following.

1.) I have checked 'File download' is set to enabled in the security settings.

2.) First party cookies and Third party cookies are set to 'Accept' and 'Always allow session cookies' in advanced privacy settings is checked.

3.) I have attempted a full reset of the browser followed by a reboot.

4.) I have recreated my domain profile.

5.) I have re-installed IE 11, I must also note that this issue did not occur in IE 8 but as soon as IE 10 was installed via windows update the issue re-occurred.

I am completely out of ideas, we are not using a proxy server and all other computers in the business seem fine.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was occurred after upgrading my work station to 64 bit windows; it may have been an issue with my roaming profile, unfortunately I cannot be certain.

I resolved the issue by moving my temporary internet files via internet explorer.

Internet explorer :: Internet Options :: Settings :: Move folder

[image]